# magento:Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in /var/www/html/rmcstore/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I installed magento patches(7405,8788,6788) to site,after that when clicking on admin sales > order >view getting error like

```
   Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in /var/www/html/rmcstore/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

how to solve this

Comment: Can u share the last part of the code before the error

Comment: not getting @karthik

Comment: when you got the error you must have changed something in code , i assume before you made change the code must be working
 jus remove the patch and check

Comment: i installed magento patches after that it will not come i think,i didnt change any code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even with very little PHP knowledge, you can always diagnose issues thanks to Magento's error reporting mechanism.

This error indicates the exact file & line of code which are responsible for it, so take the following steps:

1. Navigate through `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/` & open `Observer.php`,
2. Scroll to line 46

The line of code in 1.7 reads as follows:

```
if ($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() != 'free') {
```

Now, the error message also tells you that the following code is what is causing the issue:

```
Call to a member function getMethodInstance()
```

So after you read the line of code on line 46, you'll see that that method is applied to the $order object, this is defined just above line 46 (on line 44):

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

Comment: so how to resolve this @calypso